# variables in $.fn.customTabs messed up when called more than once

Tags: jquery, html

ok so i created a function in jQuery called `$.fn.customTabs` and i am setting variables inside of it to certain elements within the DOM. when i call it the second time, the variables are being set to different DOM elements and effecting my first call to the function.

**Any idea how to have certain instance variables with in each function call?**

EDIT

```
$.fn.customTabs = function(data,user_options) {
    $this = $(this);
    alert($this.attr('id'));
    var options = 
        {
            speed : 750,
            startIndex : 0,
            duration : 10000,
            height : "300px"
        },
        final_options = {
            "width" : "100% - 5px",
            "position" : "relative",
            "margin" : "0",
            "padding" : "5px"
        };
    $.extend(options,user_options);
    var tabPadding = parseInt(final_options.padding,10);
    var cssTabHeight = parseInt(options.height,10) - tabPadding + "px";
    $this.css(final_options);
    var num = data.length - 1;
    if(data) {
        $container = $('<ul class=\"tabsContainer\">').css({
            height : options.height,
            position : "relative",
            "list-style" : "none",
            padding : "0",
            margin : "0"
        });
        for(var count = 0; count <= num; count++) {
            $object = data[count];

            $tab = $('<li id=\"tab_' + count + '\" class=\"tab\">').css({
                height : cssTabHeight
            });

            if($object.element) {
                $object.element.css({
                    margin : "0",
                    padding : $object.element.css('padding') || "0"
                });
                if($object.element.is('a')) {
                    $tab.css({
                        "text-align" : "center" 
                    });
                    $object.element.find('img').css({
                        "max-height" : "100%",
                        "max-width" : "100%"
                    });
                } else if($object.element.is('img')) {
                    $tab.css({
                        "text-align" : "center" 
                    });
                    $object.element.css({
                        "max-height" : "100%",
                        "max-width" : "100%"
                    });
                } else {
                    $object.element.css({
                        width : "100% - " + tabPadding,
                        height : "100%"
                    });
                }
                $object.element.appendTo($tab);
            } else {

            }

            $container.append($tab);
        }
        $tabWrapper = $('<div>').html($container).css({
            overflow: "hidden"
        });
        $this.html($tabWrapper);
    } else {

    }

    var tabIndex = options.startIndex,
        x,
        tabHeight = parseInt(cssTabHeight,10) + tabPadding;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        makeInterval();
    },options.duration);

    $('.tabMenuButton').click(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        var element = this;
        var index;
        $('.tabMenuButton').each(function(i, ele) {
            if(ele == element) {
                index = i;
            }
        });
        var diffrence = index - tabIndex;
        if(diffrence < 0) {
            x = "-=" + (tabHeight*parseInt(diffrence,10));
            changeTab(x);
        } else if(diffrence > 0) {
            x = "-=" + (tabHeight*diffrence);
            changeTab(x);
        }

        tabIndex = index;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            makeInterval();
        },options.duration);
    });

    var makeInterval = function() {
        if(tabIndex != num) {
            tabIndex++;
            x = "-=" + tabHeight;
        } else {
            tabIndex = 0;
            x = "+=" + (tabHeight*num);
        }

        changeTab(x);
    }

    var changeTab = function(distance) {
        $container.animate({
            "top" : distance + "px"
        }, options.speed);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

after the second call to this function is made, the `$container` is being set to the element created in the second call for both Intervals.

BTW this code works just gets messed up when there are two of them on the same page.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring or show an example if it's not a secret.

Comment: Are you declaring the variables anywhere? Otherwise they are global, so all instances share the same variables.

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua: This is not the code you are using (at least not the full one). In other words: show us the code. -1 for asking us to fix the code you did not show.

Comment: @Tadeck there that is my entire code... i didn't post all of it cause i thought it would confuse you but there ya go

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua: It is hard to confuse me, I have seen a lot of badly written code, believe me. But you could scare me from helping you if the code is bad enough ;) In your case it looks like the problem is just usage of global variables in places where local variables should be used (see my answer). I do not know if this is the only problem, but surely one of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) when i call it the second time, the variables are being set to different DOM elements and effecting my first call to the function. Any idea how to have certain instance variables with in each function call?

The problem you are facing is the **usage of global variables in places where you should use local ones**. As a result, all the elements on which you execute the jQuery function, **share the same variables**.

These variables are:

- `$this`,
- `$container`,
- `$object`,
- `$tab`,
- `$tabWrapper`,
- and possibly other.

So it looks like you are treating normal variables with names beginning with `$` as if they were special, automatically local. **They are not local**: you are just creating global variables with dolar sign at the beginning of their names.

There are two solutions for you:

- add `var` keyword in places where you first define it, or even put all variables at the beginning of appropriate functions, with `var` keyword in front of them, or
- follow the guide of code quality tools such as JSLint: http://www.jslint.com/,

And remember: your jQuery function must work independently between elements, so **you must not use global variables**. Instead, if you need to somehow store data between calls or for some reason within the code, use one of two options:

- use closures (storing variables in outer scope, yet within the scope of jQuery function),
- use jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to attach data to specific elements (use your own function-specific naming to not interfere with other functions and/or plugins used by the user of your script),

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua: Done. Good luck next time, hope my answer helped you fix the code.